# A recursive approach to Josephus problem (OEIS 225381)

Tags: recursive-algorithms, oeis

Taking integer $x$ as input:

If $x$ is even, then return $x/2$ as series item, giving $x/2$ as input to continue the loop;

Else return ceiling($x/2$) as series item, terminate the loop;

Finally we sum over the produced series.

Assuming this function is $f(x)$.

```
f(1) = ceiling(1/2) = 1
f(2) = 2/2 + ceiling(1/2) = 2
f(3) = ceiling(3/2) = 2
f(4) = 4/2 + 2/2 + ceiling(1/2) = 4
f(5) = ceiling(5/2) = 3
f(6) = 6/2 + ceiling(3/2) = 5
f(7) = ceiling(7/2) = 4
f(8) = 8/2 + 4/2 + 2/2 + ceiling(1/2) = 8
f(9) = ceiling(9/2) = 5
f(10) = 10/2 + ceiling(5/2) = 8
f(11) = ceiling(11/2) = 6
f(12) = 12/2 + 6/2+ ceiling(3/2) = 11
f(13) = ceiling(13/2) = 7
f(14) = 14/2 + ceiling(7/2) = 11
f(15) = ceiling(15/2) = 8
f(16) = 16/2 + 8/2 + 4/2 + 2/2 + ceiling(1/2) = 16
f(17) = ceiling(17/2) = 9
f(18) = 18/2 + ceiling(9/2) = 14
```

Note that $f(x)$ is [OEIS 225381](https://oeis.org/A225381):

```
1,2,2,4,3,5,4,8,5,8,6,11,7,11,8,16,9,14
```

The question is, is there any simple rational formula to calculate the final summatory f(x) or to represent OEIS 225381?

Comment: I expect that, were a simple formula known, it would have appeared on the OEIS page.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted ? The OP has worked on it and it's original, connected to a classical problem (Josephus' problem), not a "do-my-homework-for-me" issue !

Comment: It's not *floor*, it's $\dfrac{n+1}2$ when $n$ is odd. ( $\text{floor}(1/2)=0$ )

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order to attract more attention to your question.

Comment: Thank you all. This is started as a little game (aka a Josephus problem): taking the first one at the bottom of a pile of playing cards away, then putting the "new bottom" to the top, and then taking the newest bottom (3rd one) away. If the taking-away sequence is A-K, how would you arrange the initial sequence? The first item of initial sequence (at the top) for n cards is OEIS225381(n), and the whole sequence is a(n, i). I have several python ways to solve it, and I know a(n, i) = a(n-1, i+1). But I wonder if there's a non-recursive general formula for a(n, i)  :)

Comment: My bad. "floor()" in my question is wrong, It's actually "ceil()".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a formula, but you could optimize your algorithm, since you calculate $f(x)$ repeatedly with increasing numbers, and the recursive function calls itself with lower values.

It's called *memoization*. Practically, storing the results of calls of lower values given to $f(x)$.

Something like

```
define array A

function f( x )
    if A[ x ] exists, then return A[ x ]
    if x is odd, then return ( x + 1 ) / 2
    half = x / 2
    A[ x ] = half + f( half )
    return A[ x ]
end function
```

Explanation

- declaration of an array `A` used to store calculated results from calling $f(x)$
- if $f(x)$ has already been calculated (thus its result is in `A`), return that stored result
- if not, and if $x$ is odd, just return $\dfrac{x+1}2$
- and, finally, if $x$ is even, calculate $x_{half} = \dfrac x2$, $R=x_{half}+f(x_{half})$
- store $R$ in `A[x]` (array `A` at position `x`)
- return the result $R$

---

Non recursive algorithm

```
function iter( x )
    i = 1
    while i <= x
       if i is odd, then A[ i ] = ( i + 1 ) / 2
       else 
          half = i / 2
          A[ i ] = half + A[ half ]
       end if
       i = i + 1
    end while
    return A[ x ]
end function
```

Comment: Thanks for your code anyway. I'm a programmer, so I did write python code for it. But I wonder if there's a non-recursive general formula for it.

Comment: It seems there is no formula. Using memoization, it is pretty easy to convert that code to non-recursive (in edit).